# aggregation parameter in log-normal distribution

Tags: parameters, distribution

I want to know if it is possible to get an aggregation parameter from a log-normal distribution. Usually, in ecology, it is used the aggregation parameter *k* from a negative binomial, this parameter measures the amount of clustering, or aggregation, or heterogeneity, in the data: a smaller *k* means more heterogeneity. The variance of the negative binomial distribution is μ+ μ2/k, and so as *k* becomes large the variance approaches the mean and the distribution approaches the Poisson distribution. In R the aggregation parameter is called the size parameter (Bolker, 2008).

When I fit my data in fitdistr my data fits better a log-normal distribution when compared to negative binomial, gamma and Poisson.

According to Anscombe, the logarithmic series is obtained by a limiting process from the negative binomial considering a sample of N reading letting N tend to infinity and k to zero and neglecting the zero readings.

I wonder if it is possible to get the aggregation parameter from a lognormal distribution using sdlog and meanlog or should I use the aggregation parameter k from a negative binomial given that a log-normal would be the result of a small k? Thanks in advance.

Reference: 
Bolker Benjamin M.(2008) Ecological Models and Data in R. Princeton University Press

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat unusual question, but if I understood correctly, you have a [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) fit, so there is a curve with known `mu` and `sigma`

If you pretend it is neg-binomial, it also has two parameters `n` and `p`. So the good way you could try to find size (`n`) is to find mean and variance

For [Neg-Binomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialDistribution.html)

```
mean = n*q/p
var  = n*q/p^2, where q = 1-p
```

Taking mean and variance for log-normal from the link above

```
mean/var = p = exp(- mu - sigma^2/2) / [exp(sigma^2) - 1]
q = 1 - p
n = mean * p / q = exp(mu + sigma^2/2) * exp(- mu - sigma^2/2) / [exp(sigma^2) - 1] / q = 1 / ([exp(sigma^2) - 1] * q) = 1 / (exp(sigma^2) - 1 - exp(- mu - sigma^2/2))
```

Please check my math carefully...

UPDATE

There is no one single solution for this problem. For example, to get `n` and `p` from log-normal, you could try to match mode and variance instead of mean and variance as I did